# Filter an ordered sequence in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, optimization, filter, sequence

I've got a big list that contains a lot of integer lists. I tried to write a code that exclude all lists with the ordered sequence of [1, 1, 1] in it.
Furthermore, I can not convert lists to sets because sets are unordered.
The code I've written below doesn't work because when the sequence is at the end of the list, the list go through my filter.

**I need to exclude all list that contain three consecutive 1's.**

In the example below, `list_set` is an excerpt of my list with only 4 integers in it. The code should work with lists of any length. The output should be `[[1,2,1,1]]` instead of `[[1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], [7, 1, 1, 1]]`

```py
li_set = [[1,1,1,1], [1,2,1,1], [7,1,1,1]]
res = []
for n in li_set: # Take a list
    eject = False # List is not evaluated yet
    for i in range(len(n)-2): # Give the index of the initial value of the evaluated triplet
        if eject: # If we already find the searched triplet in this list
            continue # Ignore this list
        if sum([n[i], n[i+1], n[i+2]]) == 3: # If the evaluated triplet = 3
            eject = True # Program should ignore this set
        else:
            res.append(n) # Add the good lists in a list of results
print(res)
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `sum` might lead to some error since for example `sum([1, -1, 3]) == 3`.

You can do this thanks to the `windowed` function provided by [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed)

Here is the snippet:

```py
from more_itertools import windowed

li_set = [[1,1,1,1], [1,2,1,1], [7,1,1,1]]
output = []

for sublist in li_set:
    if any(window == (1, 1, 1) for window in windowed(sublist, 3)):
        continue
    
    output.append(sublist)
print(output)
```

And it gives the expected output:

```py
[[1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

**Edit:** as suggested we can use `in` operator instead of the `any` with the loop as an alternative. It might be easier to understand:

```py
from more_itertools import windowed

li_set = [[1,1,1,1], [1,2,1,1], [7,1,1,1]]
output = []

for sublist in li_set:
    if (1, 1, 1) in windowed(sublist, 3):
        continue

    output.append(sublist)

print(output)
```

You can even reduce it to a list comprehension:

```py
from more_itertools import windowed

li_set = [[1,1,1,1], [1,2,1,1], [7,1,1,1]]
output = []

def should_keep(sublist):
    return (1, 1, 1) not in windowed(sublist, 3)

output = [sublist for sublist in li_set if should_keep(sublist)]

print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for make me know that more_itertools exists ! But does it is simpler to write the "if line" like this `if (1, 1, 1) in windowed(sublist, 3):` ?

Comment: I just checked and it is working! I don't why I was thinking that we can't use `in` with generators. I learnt something, thanks!

Comment: Love it when it's a win-win situation. You helped with my code and learn something !

Answer (score 1):

You could convert each sub list to a string and check if it contains the pattern

```
pattern = ''.join(map(str, [1, 1, 1]))
res = [l for l in li_set if pattern not in ''.join(map(str, l))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to work if the individual list has only [1,1,1] at index 1,2,3:

```
In [27]: li_set = [[1,1,1,1], [1,2,1,1], [7,1,1,1]]
    ...: result = [x for x in li_set if sum(x[1:]) != 3]

In [28]: result
Out[28]: [[1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

To make it work in a way that if [1,1,1] is found in any of the sublists, try this:

```
li_set = [[1,1,1,1], [1,2,1,1], [7,1,1,1]]
res = []
for sublist in li_set:
    bad = [True for n in range(len(sublist)) if sublist[n:n+3] == [1,1,1]]
    if not bad:
        res.append(sublist)
```

Comment: I edit my question to be more clear. Your code take the sum of all the values except the first one. If the list is bigger than 4 integers or if the [1,1,1] sequence is at the beginning it will go through the filter. I need to exclude all list that contain three consecutive 1's.

Comment: I have changed my answer based on your question. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this
it will make a `subset` of the list and find the pattern in it. if a pattern found then it will ignore it else it will include it in the output

```
pattern_to_remove = [1, 1, 1]
li_set = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], [7, 1, 1, 1]]


def sub_lists(l):
    lists = [[]]
    for i in range(len(l) + 1):
        for j in range(i):
            lists.append(l[j: i])
    return lists


output = []
for i in li_set:
    sub_list = sub_lists(i)
    if pattern_to_remove in sub_list:
        pass
    else:
        output.append(i)

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution based on `more-itertools` looks great, I can offer one without (stdlib) dependancy :

```py
pattern = [1, 1, 1]
lists = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], [7, 1, 1, 1]]


def does_not_contain_pattern(li) -> bool:
    for i in range(len(li) - len(pattern) + 1):
        if li[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern:
            return False
    else:
        return True

result = list(filter(does_not_contain_pattern, lists))
print(result)  # [[1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Actually, your `does_not_contain_pattern()` reimplementing inverted `any()`.

Comment: Indeed @OlvinRoght, using `any/all` I get this one-liner for `does_not_contain_pattern` : `return all(li[i:i+len(pattern)] != pattern for i in range(len(li) - len(pattern) + 1))`.

Comment: Much better to use `not any()` for this case, because it will stop iterating on first match, while `all()` will check every item.

Comment: @OlvinRoght `all` does "short-circuit" too. I find `not any` to be difficult to understand, while `all` is simple. But because we want to stop searching when the pattern is found, `not any` would be more efficient because it could stop early.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass generator to `any()` which will iterate over each sublist and check if it contains subset.

**Code:**

```py
li_set = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], [7, 1, 1, 1]]
sub_set = [1, 1, 1]

result = [l for l in li_set if not any(l[i: i + len(sub_set)] == sub_set for i in range(0, len(l) - len(sub_set) + 1))]
```